# Why won't my dataframe column in pandas convert from float to int?

Tags: python, pandas, tabula

I'm trying to convert a column from float to int.  When I execute the script, I don't receive an error; however, the float dtype persists.  What am I doing wrong?

The dataset was read in as a pdf and converted to csv using tabula.

```
apd_log = pd.read_csv('/home/d/my_datasets/police_log.csv')
apd_log = apd_log.astype({'Incident #': int}, errors='ignore')
apd_log.dtypes

Incident #       float64
Date              object
Time              object
Address           object
Incident Type     object
Action Taken      object
dtype: object
```

Comment: you  didn't receive an error because you passed `errors='ignore'` and It is not converting to `int` is possibly due to the presence of `NaN's` in `'Incident #'` column

Comment: Please remove the errors='ignore'. That is the reason why you're not getting an error.

Comment: There are ```NaN's``` in the column.  Sounds like I need to clean that up before I can convert.  Thanks!

Comment: @AnuragDabas is right but you can use `pd.Int64Dtype` to get what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Since `Pandas 0.24.0`, you have a [solution](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) to convert  `float` to `integer` and keep null value.
Use the dtype `pd.Int64Dtype` (or `"Int64"`).

```
>>> df['Incident #']
0    9.0
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    2.0
4    3.0
Name: Incident #, dtype: float64

>>> df['Incident #'].astype(int)  # raise an exception without errors='ignore'
...
ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

>>> df['Incident #'].astype("Int64")
0       9
1       1
2    <NA>
3       2
4       3
Name: Incident #, dtype: Int64
```